# Stock hot end for Anycubic Mega Zero 1.0?

Tags: anycubic-i3-mega

Does anyone know what hotend the Anycubic Mega Zero uses? I've found info on upgrading to a different one but I'm thinking of just buying more nozzles for now and trying other options later. I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right things when I did a Google search. The hotend I'm looking at looks like an MK8 or even a Mini Swiss but I've read it's a J-Head? Am I missing something?

[image: Photo of the Anycubic Mega Zero hotend and extruder assembly]

Answer (score 1):

The picture you have shared leads me to believe that it is an MK10 style hot end (Sometimes erroneously referred to as a Creality-style hot end)

MK10 is identified by its 'Flattened' heat sink shape with screw holes through the heat sink for mounting, Along with the smooth, un-threaded geometry of the heat break entering into the heat sink.

MK8 is similar, Consisting of the same Flattened, screw-mount heat sink design. However, the MK8 hot ends use a threaded heat break on *both* sides, rather than only on the heater block side.